# Angular 2 errors accessing router params

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm getting a typescript error when accessing router params that reads:

"app.component.ts Property ‘imageUrl’ does not exist on type ‘{ [name: string]: any}"

I'm able to get the property fine, but the error causes my server to fail at startup. Here's the code I'm using to access the imageUrl param:

```
this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(_ => {
          let childRouteSnapshot = this.route.firstChild.snapshot;
          let url = childRouteSnapshot.data.imageUrl;
```

My router param is defined as:

```
data: {
        imageUrl: '/app/assets/images/image.png',
```

Like I said, the code works, but I'm not sure if the typescript error has to do with my syntax or an outdated typescript reference.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.5",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Should I be using something other than the quick start setup from google? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know which properties will be on `data` at compile time.

You should use bracket notation instead.

```
let url = childRouteSnapshot.data["imageUrl"];
```

Comment: Ahh, perfect.  I wouldn't have thought that.  Works great.  Thanks you!